# Peoplesoft - Why does the "y" in "MMM/y" must be lower case?

Tags: peoplesoft

Why does the "y" in "MMM/y" must be lower case?

&monYear = DateTimeToLocalizedString(&curDate, "MMM/y");

Comment: The format string is case sensitive. They could've picked uppercase but most of the format characters are lowercase. Month is the exception because lowercase m is already being used for minutes. So the real question is not "Why must the y be lowercase?" It's "Why must the MMM be uppercase?"

Comment: I honestly don't get why the downvote.  Grow up, or at least man up and explain why you need to downvote.  You don't need to answer the question if you don't want to, but how welcoming to a newcomer is a are folks that downvote for no discernible purpose???  It's not the question has anything really wrong with it.  Note:  I apologize to anyone else on SO that does use the downvote for valid reasons.

Comment: @jl-peyret I didn't downvote but I also think it is a poor question because: 1. The fact that the string is case sensitive is clearly highlighted in the PS Books Language Reference for this function, so it certainly looks as if the OP has not bothered to read this before posting; 2. It is not a programming problem - they already know they need to use lowercase to get the result, so all they are asking a theoretical question about why the language designers decided to go that way.

Comment: well, its  also true that date formatting masks typically look case sensitive where MM <> mm and the like.  but... consider this - how many people and questions participate on SO wrt to PeopleSoft?  Very few.  So PS folks are stuck with IT Toolbox which is a much inferior venue, IMHO.  Downvoting, rather than welcoming, is shooting ourselves in the foot.  All for the sake of the vaunted SO purity?  It's hardly like it was one of those "do my homework" questions.

Answer (score 2):

Format specifiers are commonly case sensitive (in other languages too; not just in PeopleCode).  As one of the comments said, format specifiers are usually lowercase, with uppercase being used so that the same letter can have a different meaning.  The common example is m and M for minute and month.  You can see the various format specifiers [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E58500_01/pt854pbh1/eng/pt/tpcl/langref_PeopleCodeBuilt-inFunctionsAndLanguageConstructs_D.html#topofpage)

Comment: Find the answer in the definition of DateTimeToLocalizedString. Thanks.